Polarity of caffeine
I have to submit an investigatory project for my Ochem exams and I chose to write up a report on quantitative analysis of caffeine in different tea samples. During Extraction of caffeine, we use Dichloromethane to separate caffeine from the aqueous soluble part. Now, caffeine is a partially polar molecule. And both water and DCM are also polar. Then why is it so that caffeine dissolves in DCM and not in water? Also, if someone has done any report on extraction of caffeine then please help me out.

Hint: What is a measure of polarity? How do you define polarity? Another useful concept will be log octanol water partition coefficient.

Both water and DCM are also polar? DCM is a typical non polar solvent. "Having dipole moment" has little to do with this. Caffeine is an aromatic amine, they're a bit more soluble in acidic water solutions, but organic solvents are better for them.

There are two amide groups of caffeine. They exist predominately as zwitterionic resonance structures https://thechemco.com/chemical/caffeine/
